# How to print a message in access based on a criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

How do I print a message in a column "Outcome" based on the condition i.e if 
A = B print " Matched"
else " Not Matched"

I am trying this out in ms access

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `IIF`:

```
SELECT A, B, IIF([A]=[B], 'Matched', 'Not Matched') AS Outcome
FROM tab;
```

Warning! If columns A and B are nullable please remember that `NULL` is not equal `NULL`

Comment: Thanks! How can we use this as a part of the WHERE condition, like SELECT tab1.[A], tab2.[B], tab1.[C]
FROM tab WHERE (IIF([A]=[B], 'Matched', 'Not Matched') AS Outcome) ;

Comment: @user9230639: Your comment makes no sense, in the WERE condition you would simply use `WHERE [A]=[B]`.